# Getting the service specification and the service filter of an OSGI reference

Tags: service, reference, osgi, soa, ipojo

Let's say I have an OSGI Bundle that contains the class X. Let's say this class contains an OSGI reference to a specific service. Something like this:

```
ServiceReference[] references = context.getServiceReferences (serviceSpecification,someFilter);
```

Is there a way I can dynamically identify the service specification to which the reference is wired? Is there a way to also identify the service filter (second parameter above)?

For example, something like this:

```
System.out.println(references[0].getServiceSpecification);
System.out.println(references[0].getServiceFilter);
```

I need to find out these values in a code outside the bundle.

**Work done so far:**

I used iPOJO to get the reference attribute by creating iPOJO component instance of the bundle, and then getting its property description, as the following:

```
ComponentInstance  componentInstance = factory.createComponentInstance(configuration);
instanceDescription= (PrimitiveInstanceDescription) componentInstance.getInstanceDescription();
PropertyDescription[] propertyDescription = instanceDescription.getProperties();
```

I can get the reference name, type, value using the `propertyDescription` above, but the value is returned as an object, and I am not able to get what I need. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [Service Hooks](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/hooks/service/package-summary.html). With the Service Hooks, you can hook into service registry operations and observe the finding of services.